# Does the 1000 limit for "editing" points translate into a maximum of 500 edits?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

Suppose you had no other activity on a site, except for the fact that you earned 2 points for each edit, up to a maximum of 1000 points of reputation. That would translate into a maximum of 500 edits.

Suppose you wrote questions and/or answers that earned you say, a NEGATIVE 100 of reputation. Does that mean that you could get credit for up to 550 edits to take you up to 1000 reputation?

At some point, if you wrote enough bad questions/answers, you would get question/answer banned. Do points for edits count against such a ban?

Comment: I don't think so. The limit is for "reputation gained from approved edit suggestions", not related to any other activity you have in the site.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Except for one thing. After I reach 1000 points on a beta site, 1) My edits don't have to be peer approved, and 2) I stop getting two points an edit. So the question is, if downvotes kept you "shy" of 1000, could you still get 2 points per edit even if they totalled more than 500?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Suppose you now have 999 rep and submit edit suggestion. It gets approved and in that instance you get +2 rep. Now with 1001 rep (in beta site) you do not submit edit suggestion, but rather a full scale edit which does not go through peer review and does not give any reputation. If you then get a downvote (after submitting the edit), falling back to 999, the edit sticks and if you click edit again, it's edit suggestion yet again - and if approved, won't give you any rep as you got +1000 already. Hope that makes more sense?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That's helpful.

Comment: Also worth to mention that tag wiki edits still go through peer review way after you reach 2K (until you have 20k actually) so user with 2k from posts only can reach 3k only from tag wiki edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize:

1. Once you have full edit privilege, you no longer receive points for edits.
2. Over the lifetime of your account, you can get at most 1000 points from suggested edits.

The  trigger for 1 is your total reputation. The cutoffs are different on graduated sites vs beta sites.

The trigger for 2 is the amount received from suggested edits, *not* your reputation. Any reputation changes from getting downvoted, posting bounties, etc,  are irrelevant for the trigger of 2.